# SCIP-SDP through Matlab

Tags: scip

I am I trying to install SCIP-SDP. As I am not a Linux user, I have found the instructions for installing SCIP very confusing, and have not managed to install it.

I have then chosen to use SCIP through Matlab by using Opti. I have managed to solve some LPs with SCIP through Opti. Is it possible to use SCIP-SDP through Opti? If so, could you please give me some guidelines on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There exists an interface from the optitoolbox to SCIP-SDP, but this is quite old and will only work with SCIP-SDP 1.0, but since I haven't used the toolbox myself, I can't give you any more details. There is also the possibility to use SCIP-SDP via the neos-server, but this is also only SCIP-SDP 2.0 (and you should give a settings file, since the default settings are sometimes a little bit strange). For the most current version, you will unfortunately need to install it through the console, and this is really only tested on Linux. Perhaps you could try to use a virtual machine? If there are any specific problems with installing SCIP or SCIP-SDP (preferably on Linux), then feel free to ask, either here or via mail.

Comment: OK, I will try to install it in Linux then. I will contact you if I get stuck in the process. Thanks Tristan!